# Set difference between three sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given three sets A, B and C i have to calculate `(A - B) - C`, where - denotes set minus operator.
Can `(A - B) - C` be written as `A - (B + C)`, where + is set union operator.

I know `(A - B) - C` can be written as `(A - C) - B`.

I have tried solving this via venn diagram and intuitively also this seems correct. Is writing difference between sets in this way correct?

Comment: $A-B-C$ does not have a meaning. $A-(B-C)$ and $(A-B)-C$ are maningful.

Comment: @Kavi Sorry , i don't understand. Why is that so?

Comment: $(A \setminus B) \setminus C = (A \cap B') \setminus C= (A \cap B') \cap C'=A \cap (B' \cap C')= A \cap (B \cup C)' = A \setminus (B \cup C)$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why shouldn’t $A - B - C$ have the standard meaning $(A - B) - C$?  No one would interpret $5 - 2 - 1$ as $4$ instead of $2$.  But to be fair, it is more common to use $-$ for element subtraction which doesn’t have any ambiguity (whereas $\setminus$ is less suggestive of left-associativity).